# New to Python - can't pip install anything for Python 3.7

Tags: python, pip

I'm new using python and I'm unable to pip install anything on the command line.

I get an invalid syntax error every time I attempt this.  I would greatly appreciate any tips for how I can get this to work.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\cjayscue>py
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pip
> > >       pip install fuzzywuzzy
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           pip install fuzzywuzzy
> > >                     ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax